# How to check if a mono is empty or not?

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor

How can I check if the result of a function is `empty` and perform different actions based on it?

My method returns a `Mono<Something>`, e.g:

```
// Iterating over 5 items...
.flatMap { item ->
    repository.find(item.integration.id, item.integration.type)
    .flatMap { // Found something on the database }
    .switchIfEmpty { // will be called again   }
}
```

Why does the `.switchIfEmpty` being called when `find` and `flatMap` already had an item?

The final result that I need is to insert a document on the database if it doesn't exist and update otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

`.switchIfEmpty()` is supposed to receive an publisher that would be subscribed if the original publisher is empty. It's always called before to setup the reactive flow.

In your case you call it as a function that should return that Publisher, not the element itself. I.e., it should return a Mono. It could be a `Mono.fromCallable` for example:

```
.flatMap { item ->
    repository.find(item.integration.id, item.integration.type)
    .flatMap { // Found something on the database }
    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.fromCallable { // calculate a value if nothing found })
}
```